# Selendroid doesn't work with Protractor browser.get

Tags: android, protractor, selendroid

We are using Protractor to test our Angular web. Our E2E tests are working fine with PC version. Now I want to setup the tests to run on Android with Selendroid. I followed the setup guideline from https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/mobile-setup.md to run Android emulator and here is my protractor configuration:

```
exports.config = {
  seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
  allScriptsTimeout: 120000,
  specs: [
    'login.test.js'
  ],
  capabilities: {
    'browserName': 'android',
    emulator: true
  },
  baseUrl: 'my web site',
  framework: 'jasmine2',
  jasmineNodeOpts: {
    defaultTimeoutInterval: 300000,
  },
  onPrepare: function () {
    var wd = require('wd'),
            protractor = require('protractor'),
            wdBridge = require('wd-bridge')(protractor, wd);
    wdBridge.initFromProtractor(exports.config);
    wdBrowser.context('WEBVIEW');
    //helper functions
    global.helpers = require('./helper.js');
    //prepare spec host map
    global.helpers.prepareSpecHostMap();
    //extend protractor
    global.helpers.extendProtractor();
  }
};
```

Here is my test suite:

```
describe('Test login and logout (min-suite)', function () {

  beforeAll(function () {
    global.helpers.setHostParameters('login');
  });
  it('test login and logout success', function () {
    global.helpers.login(global.host.testUser, global.host.testPassword);
    expect(browser.getLocationAbsUrl()).toMatch('/home');
    element(by.id('userButtonGroup')).click();
    element(by.id('logoutButton')).click();
    expect(browser.getLocationAbsUrl()).toMatch('/login');
  });
});
```

When I run the tests, I'm facing a similar [issue](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/2617). I have quickly tested with a simple test like this:

```
it('test login and logout success', function () {
  browser.driver.get('my web site');
});
```

It works fine. Can someone please guide me to what I missed to make the tests work?